# How to change a Textview dynamically?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have this simple activity which suppose to change the text of TextView once the button is clicked. Instead I'm getting the application force closed unexpectadly. Here is my code for this textview change:

```
package android.GUI;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.*;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Shifts extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Utility UT2 = new Utility();

int i = 2122;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.shifts);

final TextView setDate = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.shifts);

Button setText = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setdate);
setText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    setDate.setText(i);
}
})  ;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }}
```

Comment: is the name of the textview shifts and is the name of the full layout also shifts?

Comment: if you mean by name to the id of textview than it is "setdate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your layout is missing the `TextView` with id *shifts*. Look in the logcat output for the error: is it a NullPointerException?

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
setDate.setText(i);
```

to this:

```
setDate.setText("" + i);
```

When you call [`setText(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29) the int is treated as a string resource id which you don't have, so you need to call [`setText(CharSequence)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) to set 2122 in your `TextView`

Comment: To add a bit more color, `setDate.setText(int)` (the first call), is trying to load the text from a *resource* with the ID=i.

Comment: @dmon - I actually added that. Thanks!

Comment: tried changing to a String, to a CharSequence and it's still gets stopped unexceptedly. Could it be something related to the fact that the TextView is Final?!

Comment: can you show us the layout xml? also, do you get the FC when you click on the button or before that?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling [`TextView.setText(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29), where the int is a resource id, which you probably do not have defined.

You probably mean to be calling [`TextView.setText(CharSequence)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), like this:

```
setDate.setText(i + "");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android it is very important to note that many functions have a default int argument instead of objects as that is how we reference objects.
so you will have to add (i+"") to your setView() method. And you cant modify a final object.

Comment: I understand you cant modify a Final object but if I remove the Final from the Textview I cannot have access to setDate.setText method from inside another method

Comment: The problem is that you have defined setDate within the method. istead of that you should define it as an instance member then initialize it in the oncreacte() and modify it in the onclick()

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
setDate.setText(i);
```

into

```
setDate.setText(Integer.toString(i));
```

If you pass an integer into setText it will use overloaded function which accept resource ID as a param. What you want to do is to pass the string. I highly recommend to use Integer.toString() instead of dirty tricks such as i+"".